# Scala-Play: Why are the Form default values not being picked up?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a 2.5.10 Play application and following the documentation on [Form default values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#default-values), I define a form like this:

```
@Singleton
class ComputeInSampleForm @Inject()(implicit val messagesApi: MessagesApi) {
  val Instance = Form {
    mapping(
      "impliedVolSpread" -> default(of[Double], 0.02),
      "fundingRate" -> default(of[Double], 0.0),
      "optionType" -> default(enum(OptionType), OptionType.Call),
      "sampleStart" -> jodaDate,
      "sampleEnd" -> jodaDate
    )(ComputeInSampleParameters.apply)(ComputeInSampleParameters.unapply)
  }
}
```

but the default values are not being picked up by the corresponding view. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `default` with `Mapping`s:

```
mapping(
      "impliedVolSpread" -> default(bigDecimal(scale = s, precision = p), 0.02),
      ...
)
```

You can also call `form.fill` with a `ComputeInSampleParameters` instance providing the defaults.

Comment: Strange ... it doesn't work either. You actually need to make the second parameter to `default` as `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.02)`

Comment: Your suggested `form.fill` alternative worked but I have no idea why the first one didn't work ...

Comment: I believe this is the Play documentation being slightly unclear as to what `default` means in this context. `default` specifies **the value to use if there is no corresponding field in the form submission**. If you're looking to set the default values to show when arriving at the page (i.e. the "empty form") then `form.fill()` is indeed what you need.